# Modifying Contribution and Event Templates

Tags: civievent, civicontribute, extension, templates, custom-templates

I am trying to modify the confirmation and final page (not sure of the name) for  contributions and events. I want to modify the templates like described in this post - [Why does the Contribution page amounts appear as a quanity?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9075/why-does-the-contribution-page-amounts-appear-as-a-quanity).

A few questions:

1. How do I find what template to modify?
2. How do I know where to put the custom template?
3. Is it best to just modify the template or to put this in an extension? I already have an extension with some simple JS.

I appreciate the help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the Confirm and ThankYou templates - they live here - for Contribution pages (and tree structure is very similar for Event):

[image]

Two options to override them:

1. add a custom_templates directory in the System Settings -> Directories - mimic this entire three.
2. or yes put it into your extension! I like that option better as I tend to forget about custom_php and custom_tpl when I upgrade sites. Same thing - in your extension -> copy the entire tree starting with templates - of course rename everything. Perhaps you already used civix to create your extension? Then you should already have a templates/ directory ready to be used!

Comment: Excellent - enjoy!

Comment: Karin, Turns out the table comes from templates/CRM/Price/Page/LineItem.tpl  - is very easy to remove the columns I do not want.  But I want them in some cases and not others. For example if it is an event AND they have ordered multiple tickets.  Is there a way to find what variables are available in Smarty? Thanks!

Comment: add `&smartyDebug=1` to the url of your page; for a nested template (as in your case), add the tag `{debug}` in the template itself. You need permission "view debug output" to be able to see debug info.